# I'm having trouble saving and showing data saved in ".dat" files in java

Tags: java

I have been working on a code in which you enter the information and it's saved in a ".dat" file. I have been having trouble reading the file but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with the code
if I enter :

> *Name=  gaby Office Phone=  34 Celular=989826 RFC= tuR5    Address= brownsville   Fiscal Address=  Chicago   Mold number=89*

when I try to read it back from the  file it prints out this :

> *Name=  g Office Phone= 27303493655658528 Celular= 9007336695791648 RFC=    Address=    Fiscal Address=    Mold number= 2097184*

here's the method I use to enter the information in the .dat file

```
    public static void enterSales()throws IOException
 {
RandomAccessFile sales=new RandomAccessFile("sales.dat","rw");
int tamReg=340;//Name(40)+tel(8)+cel(8)+RFC(20)+fisc(50)+ad(50)+mold(4)
long tamArchivo=sales.length();
int numReg=((int)(tamArchivo)/(tamReg));
int op=0;
int reg=0;
String nam,fisc,ad,rfc="";
long tel,cel=0;
int mold=0;

do{
  sales.seek(reg*tamReg);
  stdOut.println("Enter the salesman's name ");
  nam=stdIn.readLine();
  stdOut.println("Enter the salesman's office phone number");
  tel =Long.parseLong(stdIn.readLine());
  stdOut.println("Enter the salesman's cellphone number");
  cel =Long.parseLong(stdIn.readLine());
  stdOut.println("Enter the salesman’s RFC");
  rfc=stdIn.readLine();
  stdOut.println("Enter the salesman's address");
  ad=stdIn.readLine();
  stdOut.println("Enter the salesman's fiscal address");
  fisc=stdIn.readLine();
  stdOut.println("Enter the salesman's mold number");
  mold =Integer.parseInt(stdIn.readLine());

  if(nam.length()<40)
  {
    int dif=40-nam.length();
    for(int x=0;x<dif;x++)
      nam=nam+" ";
  }
  else
    nam=nam.substring(0,40);

  if(rfc.length()<20)
  {
    int dif=20-rfc.length();
    for(int x=0;x<dif;x++)
      rfc=rfc+" ";
  }
  else
    rfc=rfc.substring(0,20);

  if(fisc.length()<50)
  {
    int dif=50-fisc.length();
    for(int x=0;x<dif;x++)
      fisc=fisc+" ";
  }
  else
    fisc=fisc.substring(0,50);

  if(ad.length()<50)
  {
    int dif=50-ad.length();
    for(int x=0;x<dif;x++)
      ad=ad+" ";
  }
  else
    ad=ad.substring(0,50);

  sales.seek(sales.length());
  sales.writeChars(nam);
  sales.writeLong(tel);
  sales.writeLong(cel);
  sales.writeChars(rfc);
  sales.writeChars(ad);
  sales.writeChars(fisc);
  sales.writeInt(mold);

  stdOut.println("Datos del Sales");
  stdOut.println("Name= "+nam+" Office Phone= "+tel+ " Celular= "+cel+" RFC= "+rfc+" Address= "+
                 ad+" Fiscal Address= "+fisc+" Mold number= "+mold);
  stdOut.println("Do you wish to enter a new salesman? 1=SI,2=NO ");
  op=Integer.parseInt(stdIn.readLine());



}while(op==1);
sales.close();
  }
```

And this is the one I use to read the information stored in the file

```
  public static void showSales()throws IOException
  {
RandomAccessFile sales=new RandomAccessFile("sales.dat","r");
int tamReg=340;//Name(40)+tel(8)+cel(8)+RFC(20)+fisc(50)+ad(50)+mold(4)
long tamArchivo=sales.length();
int numReg=((int)(tamArchivo)/(tamReg));
String nam,fisc,ad,rfc="";
long tel,cel=0;
int mold=0; 
for(int x=0;x<numReg;x++)
{
  sales.seek(tamReg*x);
  nam="";
  fisc="";
  ad="";
  rfc="";
  for(int y=0;y<40;y++);
  nam=nam+sales.readChar();
  tel=sales.readLong();
  cel=sales.readLong();
  for(int y=0; y<20;y++);
  rfc=rfc+sales.readChar();
  for(int y=0; y<50;y++);
  ad=ad+sales.readChar();
  for(int y=0; y<50;y++);
  fisc=fisc+sales.readChar();
  mold=sales.readInt();

  stdOut.println("Name= "+nam+" Office Phone= "+tel+ " Celular= "+cel+" RFC= "+rfc+" Address= "+
                 ad+" Fiscal Address= "+fisc+" Mold number= "+mold);
}
sales.close();
 }
```

Thank you!

Comment: `readLine()` in the input...`readChar()` in the output...

Comment: I'm fairly sure that your file doesn't looks quite like that. That is, I'm pretty sure it'll have newlines. Please format it correctly, then put it in a code block instead of a block quote.